# Full width ion-segment in a ion-toolbar for smartphone

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

This is my header section:

```html
<ion-header color="primary">
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <app-my-header-component></app-my-header-component>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="topTab" (ionChange)="onTabChanged()">
      <ion-segment-button  value="send" >
         <ion-icon color="light"  title="Risultati" name="list-box">Invia</ion-icon>
         <ion-label>Risultati</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="calendar" >
         <ion-icon color="light" title="Inviate" name="stats"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Classifica</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>

      <ion-segment-button value="match" >
        <ion-icon color="light" title="Partite" name="calendar"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Partite</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

I want that the elements in the `ion-segment` section take more space. So if there are two `ion-segment buttons`, I want that each element takes 50% of the screen. In the case of 3, 33%. How Can I achieve this? In the second step, this scenario I want only for devices and not pc since the screen is bigger!

Comment: you can use ion-row and ion-col for same width for segment

Comment: Could you provide your idea with my example code?

Comment: i added the answer please check

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ion-header color="primary">
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <app-my-header-component></app-my-header-component>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="topTab" (ionChange)="onTabChanged()">
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-segment-button  value="send" >
                <ion-icon color="light"  title="Risultati" name="list-box">Invia</ion-icon>
                <ion-label>Risultati</ion-label>
             </ion-segment-button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-segment-button value="calendar" >
                <ion-icon color="light" title="Inviate" name="stats"></ion-icon>
               <ion-label>Classifica</ion-label>
             </ion-segment-button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-segment-button value="match" >
                <ion-icon color="light" title="Partite" name="calendar"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>Partite</ion-label>
              </ion-segment-button>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-segment>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, since the col are smaller than with my solution. How to fix it?

Comment: you can give col width e.g. col-3